# Puppeteer page.evaluate not working as expected

Tags: puppeteer

Can someone explain why this code isn't working. I have a console log before I run `page.evaluate()` which logs what I expect, but the console log inside `page.evaluate` never runs.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.example.com');
    page.on('response', async response => {
      const url = response.url();
      if (url.includes('something')) {
        console.log('this code runs');
        await page.evaluate(() => {
          console.log("this code doesn't run");
        });
      }
    });    
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 10):

The code inside page.evaluate is run in the browser context, so the console.log works, but inside the Chrome console and not the Puppeteer one.

To display the logs of the Chrome context inside the Puppeteer console, you can set **dumpio** to true in the arguments when launching a browser using Puppeteer:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    dumpio: true
})
```

Comment: This works as expected. Devs should point out this

Answer (score 9):

Console log doesn't work in `page.evaluate()`

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1944

Answer (score 6):

Try to use this code for display console.log from evaluate

```
page.on('console', msg => {
  for (let i = 0; i < msg.args().length; ++i)
    console.log(`${i}: ${msg.args()[i]}`);
});
page.evaluate(() => console.log('hello', 5, {foo: 'bar'}));
```

https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.20.0&show=api-event-console

Comment: This works!!! Awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Console.log works but in the browser context. I'm guessing here that you are trying to see the log in the CLI. If you want to see the log set headless to false and then see the log in the browser console.